# CheckBox List not setting all to checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem finding where I went wrong in my code. I have dynamically populated a checkbox list with a "SelectAll" list item at the bottom of the list.

When I toggle the list item "SelectAll" and set all to either checked or not it all works fine, all of the list items are changed accordingly. However,If I had selected one of the other list items prior to selecting the SelectAll item, that item will no longer be toggled  on subsequent SelectAll actions.

```
   var Activities = " Hiking,Boating,Camping,Music,Theater,News,Biking,Market,History ";
    var selectAllText = "SelectAll";

    function InitializeListItems() {
        var splits = Activities.split(",");
        splits.sort();

        for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {

            AddListItem(splits[i] );
        }
        AddListItem(selectAllText )
    }  


 function AddListItem(name ) {

        var li = " <li >   " +

           "<label style='border:none; padding-left:5px'> <input 
                   type='checkbox' value='" + name + "' id='" + name + "ID'    > " +
           name + "</label>   </li>";

        document.getElementById('FilterList').innerHTML += li
    }

    $(document).on('click', '#FilterList li', function () {

        var ip = $(this).find('input');
        ip.each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

                if ($(this).attr('value') == selectAllText) {
                    $('#FilterList').find('input').attr('checked', true);

                }
            }
            else {
                if ($(this).attr('value') == selectAllText) {
                    $('#FilterList').find('input').attr('checked', false);

                }
            }
        });




    });
```

Comment: @Sphinx No, not really. Click event is bound only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function on whatever event you want.

```
var checkboxes = doc.querySelector('input[name="mycheckboxes"]');

function uncheck(elements){
  for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
  }
}

function check(elements){
  for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = true;
  }
}
```